# Stack overflow with ToArray()

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, stack-overflow

I get a stack overflow error from the last line of the below code. I cant see why. Any ideas?

```
        var slots = from a in db.AvailableAppointments
                    where a.RequestID == reqId
                    select new
                    DataLayer.DateAndTimeslot
                    {
                        date = a.Date.ToShortDateString(),
                        timeSlot = a.Timeslot
                    };

        returnValue.DateAndTimeslot = slots.ToArray();
```

My class;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace DataLayer
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://wholesale.fluidata.co.uk/bt/AppointmentAvailabilityResponse")]

    public class AppointmentAvailabilityResponse : DataLayer.WebserviceMessage
    {
        DateAndTimeslot[] _dateAndTimeSlot;

        [DataMember]
        public DateAndTimeslot[] DateAndTimeslot
        {
            get { return _dateAndTimeSlot; }
            set { _dateAndTimeSlot = value; }
        }

    }

    public class DateAndTimeslot
    {
        private String _date;
        private String _timeSlot;

        [DataMember]
        public string date 
        {
            get { return this._date; }
            set {_date = value;}
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string timeSlot
        {
            get { return this.timeSlot; }
            set {_timeSlot = value;}
        }

    }
}
```

My table (With example data)

```
ID  RequestID   Date            Timeslot
171 3214    2005-12-28 00:00:00.000 EV
172 3214    2005-12-28 00:00:00.000 EV
173 3214    2005-12-29 00:00:00.000 EV
174 3214    2005-12-29 00:00:00.000 EV
175 3214    2005-12-30 00:00:00.000 EV
176 3214    2005-12-30 00:00:00.000 EV


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AvailableAppointments](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RequestID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Timeslot] [varchar](21) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AvalibleAppointments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here:

```
[DataMember]
public string timeSlot
{
    get { return this.timeSlot; }
    set { _timeSlot = value; }
}
```

Notice the missing `_` in the getter and the recursive call?

Should be:

```
[DataMember]
public string timeSlot
{
    get { return this._timeSlot; }
    set { _timeSlot = value; }
}
```

And by the way since I started to use [Auto implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) in C# those kind of errors went into oblivion:

```
[DataMember]
public string TimeSlot { get; set; }
```

Just a nitpicking side note: it is good coding practice to have property names start with a capital letter (`TimeSlot` instead of `timeSlot`).

Comment: +1 This is where using capital camel case for properties would have provided a better chance of catching this one earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your recursion.  You need a `_` here: `get { return this.timeSlot; }`

```
    public string timeSlot
    {
        get { return this.timeSlot; }
        set {_timeSlot = value;}
    }
```